# python: iterate in groupby pandas, add new columns based on previous value

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is:

```
id            beg                       end                 
client1     2021-10-19 16:01:01       2021-10-21 08:19:17                
client1     2021-10-21 10:41:53       2021-10-24 07:53:57  
client3     2021-10-21 09:00:00       2021-10-21 10:00:00       
client3     2021-10-21 10:00:00       2021-10-22 14:00:00             
client2     2021-10-21 10:00:00       2021-10-21 14:00:00
```

I want to add columns based on previous value of column by `id` as shown below.

If the client appears more than once then I want to create new columns on the second appearance of this client...

- `col1`  that takes the previous `end`
- `col2` that takes the current `beg` of this row (in this example, for client1 and client3).

...else put nothing in `col1`, `col2`

Expected output:

```
  id                 beg                   end                col1                col2
client1     2021-10-19 16:01:01    2021-10-21 08:19:17      -                      -          
client1     2021-10-21 10:41:53    2021-10-24 07:53:57       2021-10-21 08:19:17.  2021-10-21 10:41:53
client3     2021-10-21 09:00:00    2021-10-21 10:00:00       --                     --
client3     2021-10-21 10:00:00    2021-10-22 14:00:00      2021-10-21 10:00:00    2021-10-21 10:00:00
client2     2021-10-21 10:00:00    2021-10-21 14:00:00    2021-10-21 10:00:00   2021-10-21 14:00:00
```

Comment: I cleaned up your formatting and wording a bit. Also, make sure to also tag [tag:python]

Answer (score 0):

Let us start with the easy way (only get the previous value):

We can use `groupby`+`shift`:

```
df['col1'] = df.groupby('id')['end'].shift()
```

output:

```
        id                  beg                  end                 col1
0  client1  2021-10-19 16:01:01  2021-10-21 08:19:17                  NaN
1  client1  2021-10-21 10:41:53  2021-10-24 07:53:57  2021-10-21 08:19:17
2  client3  2021-10-21 09:00:00  2021-10-21 10:00:00                  NaN
3  client3  2021-10-21 10:00:00  2021-10-22 14:00:00  2021-10-21 10:00:00
4  client2  2021-10-21 10:00:00  2021-10-21 14:00:00                  NaN
```

But we want this condition if the group only has one row… so we can apply a mask using `where` and a condition on the group `size`:

```
g = df.groupby('id')
m = g['beg'].transform('size').gt(1)
df['col1'] = g['end'].shift().where(m, df['beg'])
df['col2'] = df['beg'].where(df['col1'].notnull())
df['col2'] = df['col2'].where(m, df['end'])
```

output:

```
        id                  beg                  end                 col1                 col2
0  client1  2021-10-19 16:01:01  2021-10-21 08:19:17                  NaN                  NaN
1  client1  2021-10-21 10:41:53  2021-10-24 07:53:57  2021-10-21 08:19:17  2021-10-21 10:41:53
2  client3  2021-10-21 09:00:00  2021-10-21 10:00:00                  NaN                  NaN
3  client3  2021-10-21 10:00:00  2021-10-22 14:00:00  2021-10-21 10:00:00  2021-10-21 10:00:00
4  client2  2021-10-21 10:00:00  2021-10-21 14:00:00  2021-10-21 10:00:00  2021-10-21 14:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you @mozway but not really what i want the value of col1 should get the value of end(i-1) and the value of col2 should get the value of beg(i). Please tell me if im not clear

Comment: @tamo007 I saw that, this doesn't change much (see update) ;)